# How to determine the probability that at least two dice will match when rolled together

Tags: probability

I'm very unlearned in probability and would appreciate learning how to do this.

I play a silly game where I roll several different dice. There is a d30, d28, d26 and two d24s. I am frequently astounded by how often these dice, when rolled, result in two or more of the five matching in value.

How can I determine the probability that two (or more) dice of different values will match, when rolled together?

I tried modifying a solution to the birthday paradox, but I'm almost certain I did something wrong as it gave me a chance of 54%.

**My Solution**

A solution to the Birthday Paradox instructed to take the probability that two individuals birthdays do not match ($\frac{364}{365}$) and raise it to the power of the number of possible matches, found with group $k$ by $\frac{(k)(k-1)}{2}$

For my problem, I took the individual chances of each die not matching and multiplied them all together. So:
$\frac{29}{30}*\frac{27}{28}*\frac{25}{26}*\frac{23}{24}^2 = 0.82$

Meaning the chances of a match is roughly 18%, or shy of 1/5.

Comment: For a simpler example, do you know how to find the probability of a pair in a 5-card poker hand?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you obtained that result.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg $1-\frac{51}{52}*\frac{50}{51}*\frac{49}{50}*\frac{48}{49}*\frac{47}{48}$ ?

Comment: The probability that the two $24$-sided dice do not match is $23/24$ since whatever value one die shows, $23$  of the $24$ possible values on the other die differ from that value.

Answer (score 4):

The probability of *not* getting any matches is easiest to compute if you imagine rolling the dice with *fewest* sides *first*. This ensures that the numbers you've already rolled are always *possible* outcomes of the next roll, so you don't need to divide into cases depending on that, which could easily get unwieldy.

- The first d24 never matches anything, so the probability of surviving that roll is $1$.
- The second d24 rolls different from the single number you have yet with a probability of $\frac{23}{24}$.
- Assuming you've survived the first two rolls, the d26 rolls different from the two different numbers you have yet with a probability of $\frac{24}{26}$.
- The d28 rolls different from the three numbers you have yet with a probability of $\frac{25}{28}$.
- The d30 rolls different from the four numbers you have yet with a probability of $\frac{26}{30}$.

The final probability of getting all-different outcomes is
$$ 1 \cdot \frac{23}{24} \cdot \frac{24}{26} \cdot \frac{25}{28} \cdot \frac{26}{30} \approx 0.68 $$

Comment: Thank you! That solved the missing piece in my mind!